# background url multiple images

Tags: css

I have a background of navigation as three images (left, right, center)
I did some code that looks like this:

```
.navigation-wrapper {
    background: url('../images/navigation-background-left.png') left top no-repeat,
    url('../images/navigation-background-right.png') right top no-repeat,
    url('../images/navigation-background-center.png') center repeat-x;
   height: 65px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

How can i remove image positioned center on sides? I need a solution that will start center image in 10px left end it in 10px right

Solution:
I have solved this:

html:

```
 <nav id="navigation" class="navigation-wrapper">
    <ul class="navigation-content">
        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#">Wiki</a></li>
        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#">TS3</a></li>
        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#">English</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
/* navigation styles */

.navigation-wrapper {
    background: url('../images/navigation-background-left.png') left top no- repeat,
    url('../images/navigation-background-right.png') right top no-repeat;
    height: 65px;
}

.navigation-content {
    background: url('../images/navigation-background-center.png')repeat-x;
    margin: 0 20px;
    height: inherit;
}

.navigation-item {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navigation-item > a {
    min-width: 125px;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to stretch rather than repeat the centre image? If so, you could use `calc` to adjust the `background-size` to accommodate the left and right images. http://jsfiddle.net/hjmp6cs4/5/

Comment: Since you're new here, please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to have a look at this problem from a different angle? Maybe it is easier to create 3 different blocks with one background and then have a Wrapper having "display: flex".

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>

<style>
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
}
.wrapper > div {
   flex-grow:1
}
.one { background....}
.two { background....}
.three { background....}
</style>
```

Because with flexbox you can specify easily width of any block inside "wrapper" and any param for children block.

Comment: it will probably work, but im obliged to do this as one element

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to stretch rather than repeat the center image, you can use `calc` to adjust the `background-size` to accommodate the left and right images,

Images used:

[image]
[image]
[image]

```css
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

div {
  height: 98px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwr7q.png) left no-repeat,
              url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l21sa.png) center no-repeat, 
              url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB6nr.png) right no-repeat;
  background-size: 27px, calc(100% - 54px) 100%, 27px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

`background-size` becomes the width of the element minus the combined width of the left and right images.

Obviously this will depend entirely on wether your center image is suitable to be stretched or not.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple background-positions.

Another option, use only the left and right backgrounds, and put the middle one in a :before pseudo element.

Example (not tested)

```
#my-element:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: url(center-part.png) top left repeat-x;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1; /* move back */
}
```

Comment: Planning on elaborating on this a little? Maybe with an example? Or are you going to leave your answer as just three words?

Comment: Updated with another solution and an untested example to help you move along with it.

Comment: To help me "move along with it"? What's that mean?

Comment: To help you finishing the problem. (Sorry if it comes out wrong, English is not my native language)

Comment: Solution with z-index won't work. Background position has alternative property (some like z-index) that works depends on order of declaration background-url images